# Meaning of "surrealistically" in an NYT article

Tags: meaning

I was reading [this article](http://india.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/10/22/why-i-left-india-again/) from the New York Times and I came across the word `surrealistically`. I know surreal means something resembling a dream. But I am not sure what is it that the author wants to express.

Here is the context:

> In any breakup, there is this moment when a person who was a part of you just an instant ago becomes a surrealistically familiar stranger.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Surrealistically* is an adverb of *surreal* which can mean *unreal* or *fantastic*. Thus this person seems both like a stranger and someone familiar, something pretty surreal. In the example, *surrealistically* modifies the word *familiar*.

Comment: hmm, I am sorry, but I am not able to understand how can something be 'strange' yet 'familiar' at the same time. Even if it/the person seems 'surreal' i.e. 'resembling a dream'

Comment: That's the whole point: it's surreal or strange or bizarre or unreal or incomprehensible that this person who once so close to you and you know so well appears to you like a stranger.

Comment: ohh, okay, now I get it. Thanks Hugo for explaining and also for editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Surreal and its derivatives refer to the [Surrealist movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrealism). (I don't know if there was an earlier usage of "surreal" and its derivatives in English.) Used colloquially, and compared to *unreal*, *dreamy* or other close synonyms, it implies that the absurdity is deliberate. In other words, meaningful meaninglessness.

Comment: Surrealism began in the 1920s, and oh, look: "[surreal]"(http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=surreal) is from 1936, a back formation from "surrealism" ("[surrealism](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=surrealism)" coined in 1917, adopted for the surrealist movement in the 1920s). Sur = beyond, realism = realism.

Comment: Are you impliying something here?

Comment: No, you said `I don't know if there was an earlier usage of "surreal" and its derivatives in English.` so I checked and was surprised that *surreal* came after *surrealism*, and both relatively recently. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=surreal%2Csurrealism&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for extra confirmation.